# showing objects with Start-End dates falling in date range

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, math

I want to display events within a given month, the event has a start and end date, I cannot find a way to accommodate for events that span more than 2 month.
I tried the following, discarding the syntax (it's episerver find client API)

```
currentEvents = SearchClient.Instance.Search<EventPage>()
               .Filter(page => page.FromDate.Exists() & page.ToDate.Exists())
               .Filter(page => page.FromDate.InRange(start, end, true, true) | page.ToDate.InRange(start, end, true, true))
```

let's assume some event has starting date of '20/11/2014' and an ending date of '10/2/2015', by logic it falls in month 1, but using the above logic it will not show.
any idea?

Comment: please close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you are asking try this

```
currentEvents = SearchClient.Instance.Search<EventPage>()
               .Filter(page => page.FromDate.Exists() & page.ToDate.Exists())
               .Filter(page => page.FromDate >= start && page.EndDate <= end)
```

Comment: the event don't have to be contained in the month, it can start at 1/5/2014 and end at 1/7/2015 (dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: so you want the opposite? Show me an example of working and not working example

Comment: say event1 {start:'1/2/2014',end:'1/4/2014'} and we want to get events for month 3, event1 will fall in the criteria along others that either start in month 3 or ends in month 3. hope i made my self clear

Comment: which values have start and end? 3?

Comment: start and end values can be any value as long as start<end, i want to get events that are active in any time during a given month, March for example.

Comment: why my solution doesn't work? if you check 3 the test wil be successful because 3> startdate(2) and 3 < enddate(4)

Comment: your solution assume that the event starts and finish in the same month, which is not always the case

Comment: why do you say that? which is the type of `FromDate` and `EndDate`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66271/discussion-between-faby-and-sarepta).